# Proper way to handle third-party Python packages for distribution of a C++ application with Pyhton embedded?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-c-api

I am embedding Python in my C++ program. Basically, my C++ program serves as a framework, with Python handling scripting tasks. For instance, users can customize a task in the script, and my C++ script is responsible for executing this task. I've tested the Python C API and it seems to be able to accomplish this.

The problem I'm currently facing is how to handle third-party Python packages, such as numpy, when distributing my program. Here's my process so far:

First, I downloaded the Windows embeddable package (64-bit) (The Zip file) and used its DLLs to link to my C++ program. I tested some basic code and everything worked fine.

Next, I installed the packages I needed using pip and placed them in a venv, ensuring that the folder containing the venv would be distributed with my program. However, this is where I ran into problems, as the Python interpreter complained that it couldn't find these packages.

I found a statement in the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-embeddable-package):

> Third-party packages should be installed by the application installer alongside the embedded distribution. Using pip to manage dependencies as for a regular Python installation **is not supported** with this distribution, though with some care it may be possible to include and use pip for automatic updates. In general, third-party packages should be treated as part of the application (“vendoring”) so that the developer can ensure compatibility with newer versions before providing updates to users.

This has left me even more confused about how to handle third-party packages. If pip can't be used to manage these packages, what other methods are there?

So, my questions are:

1. What is the correct and proper way to handle packages when distributing a program with embedded Python? How should I download, organize, and distribute these packages with my exe?
2. Why can't pip be used to manage libraries when using embedded Python (i.e., the pythonxy.dll)? What's the difference between pythonXY.dll and the regular pythonXY.exe when it comes to importing packages?

Because the `Windows embeddable package (64-bit)` ZIP file does not have a pip in it.
So i use a regular python installer to install same version python to be able to use the pip.
I have a venv created like this:

```
cd res/myfolder
python -m venv myenv
cd myenv
./Scripts/activate
pip install ...
```

then in cpp code:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('res/myfoder/myenv/Lib/site-packages')");
```